# WS - Setting string in request headers creates a list

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.3

Maybe the title isn't explicit enough.

I'm using scala PlayFramework 2.3, and WS library to send request to other websites.

My issue is that when I log

`WS.url(url).withHeaders("OAuth-Token" -> token).headers()`

I get

```
Map(OAuth-Token -> List("5ad12543-fed8-4df6-8830-c97030caee09"))
```

Which can't work because the token is set in a list despite the fact that `token` is a simple String.

Is there a way to do something whithout upgrading Play's version or even some hack with WS library ?

Comment: Why don't you try `.headers.get("OAuth-Token")` this won't give you a list.

Comment: It gives now an Option[List]. I think the problem is that the .withHeaders method format the string into a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally resolved it. 
The problem was that in my header it was :

```
OAuth-Token: "5ad12543-fed8-4df6-8830-c97030caee09"
```

The quotes have no reason to be here.

When I parsed the json data of token, I did :

```
val token = (res.json.as[JsObject] \ "access_token").toString()
```

It should have been :

```
val token = (res.json.as[JsObject] \ "access_token").as[String]
```